# Domain range of a complex equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am supposed to determine the domain range of this equation:

$$y=\sin\ln(x^{2}-1)+\frac{1}{x-100} $$

but I am not sure where how to start, especially if there's on the beginning **sin ln(x^2 - 1)**.

Every advise will be appreciated :)

Comment: The sine function can always be evaluated, so that doesn't affect the domain.  The restrictions on the domain are caused by the denominator of the ratio and by the fact that logarithms are only defined for _positive_ numbers, so we must have $ \ x^2 \ - \ 1 \ > \ 0 \ $ .

Comment: so it means that x > -1 and x < 1, right?

Comment: You wrote that backwards: you want $ \ |x| \ > \ 1 \ $ . Then you need to drop $ \ x \ = \ 100 \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sin[\ln(x^2-1)]$ will remain defined and finite for all real values of $\displaystyle\ln(x^2-1)$

$\displaystyle\ln(x^2-1)$ will  remain defined and finite if $x^2-1>0$

and $\dfrac1{x-100}$  will  remain defined and finite if $x-100\ne0$

Now if $\displaystyle x\to100^+,\dfrac1{x-100}\to+\infty$ and $\displaystyle x\to100^-,\dfrac1{x-100}\to-\infty$ and the sine function will remain bound in $\in[-1,1]$